# getStream.io: How to fetch messages count in channel - swift

Tags: swift, getstream-io

To pull messages in the channel in the document (getstream.io)

```
chatChannel?.unreadCount
```

But I want to pull the number of all messages in the channel. I couldn't find any information about it in the documentation. Anyone have any knowledge on this?

Comment: You need to setup a webhook and count itself yourself if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available in Stream's chat SDK, we only offer the `unreadCount` as you've already pointed out.

For GetStream related questions, it's best to use our support channel https://getstream.io/contact/support/, to get faster and better responses.